# Cannot change header background in Bootstrap theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make some changes to a Bootstrap theme but I have stumbled upon a weird issue. When I try to change the header background image, I get a "Failed to load the given URL" message in Firebug.

The new background I am trying to use is now in the same folder as the previous working background, so I am absolutely sure the path is correct.

This is what I have tried so far:

- Double checked that the new background image file name is correct
- The current background file name is `background.jpg`, so I have tried naming the new background the same
- Deleted the browser cache
- Resized the new background to make it exactly the same dimensions as the old one

None of these worked, I still get the same message in Firebug. This is the relevant code:

```
.header_part{
    background: url("images/background.jpg") repeat scroll center center / cover rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Just to note: the path is correct, this CSS file is in the root folder of the site, so I don't need to `..` to get back to the `images` folder.

Comment: Maybe the url needs to be in https.

Comment: @claudios no, the background is a local resource so I don't need an HTTP/HTTPS link. This was a permission issue, please see my answer below.

Comment: I see. glad you figured it out on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have obviously found a solution 20 seconds after posting the question. It was a permission issue, the new image was not readable by the web server. Adding read permissions solved the issue.

I found out by right-clicking on the page and selecting "View Background Image" in Firefox, at which point I saw a **Forbidden** page saying

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /images/background2.jpg on this server.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class name is correct. And if you want with background cover just try this:

```
 .header_part {
     background:url(/images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center cover;
     background-position:top;
     height:auto;
     display:block;
     width:100%;
     text-align:center;
  }
```